# Removing \item achievement, \item subachievement from moderncv banking template

Tags: moderncv

I am new to LaTeX and currently trying to create my CV using the Modern cv Banking template. Under the section for experience I would like to remove all the `\item Achievement.\item subachievement` etc. I have tried to comment `%` to remove it, but then i get the error message: runaway argument?

Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no   longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
\begin{itemize}%
\item Sub-achievement (a);
\item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
\begin{itemize}
\item Sub-sub-achievement i;
\item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
\item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
\end{itemize}
\item Sub-achievement (c);
\end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line   1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.Se!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the last line you commented:

```
%\end{itemize}}
```

Did you saw the second `}` there?  This closing bracket is needed to close the last parameter of command `\cventry`.

So you need to bring the last `}` into the next line like this:

```
%\end{itemize}%
} % end of \cventry.
```

See the following code fragment. There I commented each `itemize`. Please see that I wrote the last bracket in a new line!

```
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
%\begin{itemize}%
%\item Achievement 1;
%\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  %%\begin{itemize}%
  %%\item Sub-achievement (a);
  %%\item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    %%%\begin{itemize}
    %%%\item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    %%%\item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    %%%\item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    %%%\end{itemize}
  %%\item Sub-achievement (c);
  %%\end{itemize}
%\item Achievement 3.
%\end{itemize}% <=======================================================
} % end of cventry! <===================================================
```

With that comments the resulting code is:

```
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements.%
} % end of cventry! <===================================================
```

and each opening `{` has a closing `}`. That code compiles without error message ...

The following MWE compiles without error:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}
\quote{Some quote}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
%\begin{itemize}%
%\item Achievement 1;
%\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  %%\begin{itemize}%
  %%\item Sub-achievement (a);
  %%\item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    %%%\begin{itemize}
    %%%\item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    %%%\item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    %%%\item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    %%%\end{itemize}
  %%\item Sub-achievement (c);
  %%\end{itemize}
%\item Achievement 3.
%\end{itemize}% <=======================================================
} % end of cventry! <===================================================
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 2}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}

\end{document}
```

and results in this pdf:

[image: part of page, showing changed part of code ...]